# Client Side Script to Display all Images from another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I want to have a form on my page take user input, a URL to be precise, and once that field is complete, have the script go to the destination URL that was entered (in the background), and display all images on that page in a thumbnail view for the user to select. I have been able to get it to work using php but want a client side solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is restricted by the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). It will not be able to read the other site unless it supports [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control). Other option is to use a local proxy [serverside langauge] on your domain to fetch the content.

Comment: How does facebook source the images when one shares a link to a website?

Comment: I believe they use an iframe element

Comment: More than likely, they are doing what this answer suggests. Same origin policies completely disappear when working on the server-side. It would be relatively straightforward to make a back-end request to the third party site, pull the images and send the URLs back to the browser, either on a new page or in an AJAX response.

Comment: So, could a possible solution be to use jquery to display the iframe once the input has been completed, and display only the images from the url?

Comment: @SindriGuðmundsson The issue with using an `iframe` is the client-side *still* can't parse the returned data for `img` URLs (due to the aforementioned same origin policy, and the various browser security restrictions around that).

Comment: I thought he meant the user's picture (badge) when you click like on a webpage, so my comment was not addressing what @StevenJohnson asked.

Comment: @Matt So if Facebook is doing it without violating the origin policy, are they doing something server side? It just seems like it is being done natively on the client side.

Comment: Yes, 100% it has to be server-side. It appears to be client-side because they're more than likely sending the image URLs back (from their own servers) as an AJAX response (JSON, JSONP or iframed).

Comment: My next question is this. I am thinking that it is done client side because it gives me default images for links to my blog that aren't avaiable to anyone else
like the tools icon that is an image an administrator can click to edit stuff...but it won't show those images if I am on another computer doing the same thing on Facebook. Would this not be something client side?

Answer (score 1):

Client side solution would be tricky. Most browser don't allow cross-domain AJAX calls.

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy